# Pi Zero W v1.1 crashes when I enable SSH

Tags: raspberry-pi-zero

Ive been having trouble with my Pi Zero W.

1. I tried to setup headless SSH over WiFi. I did not worked.
2. I tried an image without the headless setup. The pi boots ok, but the HDMI signal glitches, comes and goes. But I ignored that HDMI for trying to get more info.
   2.a) I enabled the WiFi in raspi-config. I was able to ping addresses, all good.
   2.b) I enabled SSH in raspi-config. The system crashed and never recovered. the last thing I could see on the screen was some memory access errors and interrupts highlighting a critical error. Power cycle multiple times, the device just does not boot anymore.

Please advice.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is all about programming. Your question sound like it's better asked at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.